# React: is it possible to add an item to a list without updating its siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('Let's assume this does something slow...');
    return <li>{this.props.text}</li>;
  }
}


class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }
  addItem = text => {
    this.setState({
      // Mutates the array reference... is there a way around it?
      items: this.state.items.concat({ id: Math.random(), text }),
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addItem(Math.random())}>Add Item</button>
        <ul>
          // This will run on every render, re-rendering the whole list...
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <Item key={item.id} text={item.text} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible at all to make it so the existing list remains, and I simply add a new item to the top/bottom without calling `render()` of its siblings?

Comment: You can make `Item` a `PureComponent`, since it's keyed (and I assume text isn't changing) then it shouldn't re-render as props haven't changed

Comment: Wow thank you... duh. I thought componentShouldUpdate of Component, returns true only if the props change?

Comment: nope, if the parent re-renders and the parent is passing props to it, then a regular component re-renders. There's no inbuilt prop checking for regular components. Pure components do the shallow prop equality check each time, and beyond that for more involved `shouldComponentUpdate`s you gotta write your own.

Comment: As a side note, for your array mutation, you can use spread to create a new array without having to mutate state: `items: [...this.state.items,{ id: Math.random(), text }]`

Comment: @Jayce444 `.concat` does the same as spread here. I can't simply push to an array without calling setState somewhere.

Comment: oh true, `.concat` returns a new array. In which case, there's no problem here. You're not "mutating the array reference", you're creating a new array. That's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A React `Component` will always be re-rendered, but a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` with a shallow prop and state comparison, so it will not re-render unless the props are changed.

```js
class Item extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Let's assume this does something slow...");
    return <li>{this.props.text}</li>;
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  addItem = text => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { items: [...prevState.items, { id: Math.random(), text }] };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.addItem(Math.random())}>Add Item</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map(item => (
            <Item key={item.id} text={item.text} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```